# How would I return an empty string on a select if any of the values are null?

Tags: sql

I have a table that holds drafted data. Most of the values on the table are nullable. I want to return an empty string in the case the value is null and I'm grabbing and copying the draft data onto the frontend. What would be the best way to handle this? I understand I can use ISNULL(variable, '') but don't want it to do that for every single value. Or a ternary on the front end to return a empty string if null. Would there be a better way to handle this?

Comment: you might use pivot. but there is no easy way. alternatively you may consider to use dynamic sql but it is not advised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a trigger on your table before insert or update and populate the fields you want with an empty value for all values that match your "treat null as empty" rule.

In my opinion changing data model to satisfy UI requirements is not a great idea. I would rather have a transformer in the middle (or a custom RowMappeer) that will do the transformation on the data already pulled from the database.

Also note that for some databases (such as Oracle) an empty string and a null are interchangeable in which case my suggestion to use a trigger won't work.

I know you said you did not want to use ISNULL but this is the main reason this function exists so I would rather start using it. If you have lots of such fields you can always use a clever editor to help you build your query using ISNULL rather than typing.

Comment: Thank you! I'll probably stick to ISNULL then. Thank you for the great explanation!

Comment: He he you may also want to accept my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nvl sql function, which allows you to change null value for any value you want.